# how to write to unix fifo in c#

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to write to linux fifo using both `File.WriteAllText(string)` as well as AppendAllText, this is what I get:

The code is simply

```
void Foo()
{
    File.AppendAllText("fifo", "blah");
}
```

file is "fifo" it was created using

```
mkfifo fifo
```

blah is random string I am trying to write there. I am getting this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support seeking
  at System.IO.FileStream.Seek (Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
  at System.IO.File.AppendAllText (System.String path, System.String contents) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at listener.User.InitialiseClient (System.Object data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: The stream does not support seeking
  at System.IO.FileStream.Seek (Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor (string,bool)
  at System.IO.File.AppendAllText (System.String path, System.String contents) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at listener.User.InitialiseClient (System.Object data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

the file was created using mkfifo, I can for example do `echo test >> file` but I would like to use c# function rather than calling external binary

Comment: Show us your code. I'm guessing that one of those functions is relying on being able to seek into the stream - which the fifo isn't suppoting.

Comment: the code is very simple, literally just a call to functions I mentioned, see updated

Comment: What's the exact filename? Are you sure you're not trying to write to a system device of some sort? (just guessing, since it's linux)

Comment: yes I am writing to correct file, filename is irrelevant to this question, but in this case it's "fifo" (in question I posted just "file") I can write to that file using any other linux tool, like output redirecting from echo, but not from c#

Comment: you can simply reproduce it by creating own fifo (using mkfifo) and writing to it

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use the high-level function `AppendAllText` you could open the `FileStream` for writing and then wrap it in a `StreamWriter` and write through that.

I'm assuming that `AppendAllText` is trying to seek to the end of the `FileStream` before calling `Write` which doesn't make sense in the context of a fifo/Named Pipe.

```
void Foo()
{
    FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite( "fifo" );

    using ( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs) )
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Blah");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **mkfifo** creates what is called a [Named Pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) for inter-process communication (IPC).

The error is your question clearly states - *The stream does not support seeking*. Mono thinks the file is a normal stream which it's not.

You should check out the namespace **System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.Unix** on [GitHub](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Runtime.Remoting/System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Ipc.Unix).